# python: splitting a file based on a key word

Tags: python, parsing

I have this file:

```
GSENumber   Species  Platform  Sample  Age  Tissue   Sex       Count
GSE11097    Rat     GPL1355 GSM280267   4   Liver   Male    Count
GSE11097    Rat     GPL1355 GSM280268   4   Liver   Female  Count
GSE11097    Rat     GPL1355 GSM280269   6   Liver   Male    Count
GSE11097    Rat     GPL1355 GSM280409   6   Liver   Female  Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261 GSM284967   5   Heart   Male    Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261 GSM284968   5   Heart   Male    Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261 GSM284969   5   Heart   Male    Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261 GSM284970   5   Heart   Male    Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261 GSM284975   10  Heart   Male    Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261 GSM284976   10  Heart   Male    Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261 GSM284987   5   Muscle  Male    Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261 GSM284988   5   Muscle  Female  Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261 GSM284989   30  Muscle  Male    Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261 GSM284990   30  Muscle  Male    Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261 GSM284991   30  Muscle  Male    Count
```

You can see here there is two series (GSE11097 and GSE11291), and I want a summary for each series; The output should be a dictionary like this, for each "GSE" number:

```
Series      Species  Platform AgeRange Tissue   Sex   Count
GSE11097    Rat     GPL1355     4-6    Liver    Mixed    Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261     5-10   Heart    Male     Count
GSE11291    Mouse   GPL1261     5-30   Muscle   Mixed    Count
```

So I know one way to do this would be:

1. Read in the file and make a list of all the GSE numbers.
2. Then read in the file again and parse based on GSE number.

e.g.

```
import sys

list_of_series = list(set([line.strip().split()[0] for line in open(sys.argv[1])]))

list_of_dicts = []
for each_list in list_of_series:
    temp_dict={"species":"","platform":"","age":[],"tissue":"","Sex":[],"Count":""}
    for line in open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()[1:]:
          line = line.strip().split()
          if line[0] == each_list:
                temp_dict["species"] = line[1]
                temp_dict["platform"] = line[2]
                temp_dict["age"].append(line[4])
                temp_dict["tissue"] = line[5]
                temp_dict["sex"].append(line[6])
                temp_dict["count"] = line[7]
```

I think this is messy in two ways:

1. I've to read in the whole file twice (in reality, file much bigger than example here)
2. This method keeps re-writing over the same dictionary entry with the same word.

Also, There's a problem with the sex, I want to say "if both male and female, put "mixed" in dict, else, put "male" or "female".

I can make this code work, but I'm wondering about quick tips to make the code cleaner/more pythonic?

Comment: Why do you need to read the file twice?  Why not just read it once to a list with readlines() and then if you need to iterate more than once, iterate the list.

Comment: This is something that should be done in a query language I think. E.G. load it into mysql and write a query. However, I'm bored at work so I'm writing up a possible solution for you now

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Max Paymar that this should be done in a query language. If you really want to do it in Python, the pandas module will help a lot.

```
import pandas as pd

## columns widths of the fixed width format
fwidths = [12, 8, 8, 12, 4, 8, 8, 5]

## read fixed width format into pandas data frame
df = pd.read_fwf("your_file.txt", widths=fwidths, header=1,
                 names=["GSENumber", "Species", "Platform", "Sample",
                        "Age", "Tissue", "Sex", "Count"])

## drop "Sample" column as it is not needed in the output
df = df.drop("Sample", axis=1)

## group by GSENumber
grouped = df.groupby(df.GSENumber)

## aggregate columns for each group
aggregated = grouped.agg({'Species': lambda x: list(x.unique()),
                         'Platform': lambda x: list(x.unique()),
                         'Age': lambda x: "%d-%d" % (min(x), max(x)),
                         'Tissue': lambda x: list(x.unique()),
                         'Sex': lambda x: "Mixed" if x.nunique() > 1 else list(x.unique()),
                         'Count': lambda x: list(x.unique())})

print aggregated
```

This produces pretty much the result you asked for and is much cleaner than parsing the file in pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def main():
    data = read_data(open(sys.argv[1]))
    result = process_rows(data)
    format_and_print(result, sys.argv[2])

def read_data(file):
    data = [line.strip().split() for line in open(sys.argv[1])]
    data.pop(0) # remove header
    return data


def process_rows(data):
    data_dict = {}
    for row in data:
        process_row(row, data_dict)
    return data_dict

def process_row(row, data_dict):
    composite_key = row[0] + row[1] + row[5] #assuming this is how you are grouping the entries
    if composite_key in data_dict:
        data_dict[composite_key]['age_range'].add(row[4])
        if row[5] != data_dict[composite_key]:
            data_dict[composite_key]['sex'] = 'Mixed'

        #do you need to accumulate the counts? data_dict[composite_key]['count']+=row[6]

    else:
        data_dict[composite_key] = {
           'series': row[0],
           'species': row[1],
           'platform': row[2],
           'age_range': set([row[4]]),
           'tissue': row[5],
           'sex': row[6],
           'count': row[7]
        }

def format_and_print(data_dict, outfile):
    pass
    #you can implement this one :)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I made the assumption that you are grouping the data by series, species and tissue. Hence the composite key.